# How to "git push" to private repository with prompt for username and password?

Tags: git, github

I've cloned my *private* [Github](https://github.com) repository onto my CentOS 6 machine (git version 1.7.1). Can I somehow set up my local git repository to always prompt for both username and password when typing in `git push`?

The same username is not always going to be used.

[image: Private repository]

```
$ cat .git/config 

[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = https://github.com/USER/PRIVATE-REPO.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

When I perform `git push` right now I get this:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/Industriromantik/render-linux.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

If I execute the following, the push is successful:

```
git push https://MY-GITHUB-USERNAME@github.com/USER/PRIVATE-REPO
```

...however, I am seeking to just execute `git push` and get prompted for *both* username and password, if at all possible.

Comment: Private meaning that it is merely a git repo that you're hosting from your own machine?

Comment: Are there any contributors listed in your private repo's settings?

Comment: No, I mean I chose "Private" when creating the repository via the github website.

Comment: No, there are no contributors in my repository settings.

Comment: Try adding a contributor and see if that opens up a prompt when trying to push.

Comment: Adding a contributor does not open up a prompt when executing `git push`.

Comment: I cloned a private repo from github, and I'm getting the prompt. Would you share your clone invocation?

Comment: A normal `git clone <private github repo url> and `git push origin <branch>` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

try to add a gitconfig with your username as below link

https://gist.github.com/pksunkara/988716

Comment: I wish to do exactly the reverse of what you have suggested. I do not want to cache the username. I want the command `git push` to _always_ ask for username and password.

Comment: sorry for my misunderstanding git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=1'  or you can remove your credentials, usually guys are asking how to store credentials !!

Comment: git config --global --unset credential.helper

Comment: I cloned my private repository and tried `git config --global --unset credential.helper` but this will only prompt me for my password, not the username. Did I miss something?

Comment: could you please print you .gitconfig

Comment: Sure, I added my git config to the original question.

Comment: try these cmd maybe your credentials are stored on many levels                git config --local --unset credential.helper
git config --global --unset credential.helper
git config --system --unset credential.helper

Comment: `--local` is an invalid option for me (git version 1.7.1). I ran all your suggested commands but I'm still getting the same 403 error. See original question, I added the full error message.

Answer (score 1):

Clone the repository using `https://`

```
$ git clone https://github.com/user/private-repo.git/
```

Since (it seems that) *https* connections don't cache the password (nor the username, unless you give it in the URL), git will always ask you for the password (and the username):

```
$ git push
Username for 'https://github.com': USER
Password for 'https://USER@github.com': ****
$
```

Comment: Your suggestion gives me an error: `Initialized empty Git repository in /home/fredrik/repo/.git/
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/user/repo.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed`

Comment: What do you get when executing `git --version`?

Comment: this is with `git version 2.6.2`

Comment: username password has been discontinued